# Корутина: cancel() не останавливает корутину

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

Коррутина не останавливается черзе cancel().

Что я делаю:

- захожу во фрагмента. в нем есть кнопка, которая отправляет сетевой запрос. после получения ответа - надо обработать View на основе ответа.
- это код обернут в Коррутину
- нажимаю на кнопку
- через прогармму Фидлер я торможу отправку запроса / получения ответа
- ухожу с Фрагмента
- в onDestroy Фрагмента я выключаю Коррутину
- спускаю Фидлер с цепи (отправляю запрос или получаю ответ)

код:

```
private var testScope = MainScope()

...............

fcc_next?.setOnClickListener {  
    testScope.launch {
        Log.e("!!!", "поехали!! ")
        viewModel.getAll()
        Log.e("!!!", "а я все еще рабтаю! ")
    }

}

......................

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    testScope.cancel()
    Log.e("!!!", "Дестрой")
}
```

что показывает Лог:

```
2021-10-26 14:03:02.881 17716-17716/ E/!!!: поехали!! 
2021-10-26 14:03:07.804 17716-17716/ E/!!!: Дестрой
2021-10-26 14:03:12.927 17716-17716/ E/!!!: а я все еще рабтаю!
```

`14:03:02` - я нажал кнопку, Фидлер блокировал запрос
`14:03:07` - я ушел с фрагмента. сработал onDestroy, а значит и сработал testScope.cancel()
`14:03:12` - отпускаю Фидлер. видно, что не сработал cancel

Answer (score 1):

Если в корутине нет других suspend функций (которые тоже должны быть отменяемыми) и нет проверки на отмену корутины, то её не получится отметить, подробнее тут https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#making-computation-code-cancellable

Ещё данная проблема может возникать из-за того, что вы ловите CancellationException в try и не перебрасывает его в catch

Ps для задач вроде похода в сеть корутины нужно создавать во ViewModel, а не в фрагменте/активити

Comment: у меня viewModel.getAll() - это suspend функция. я сейчас добавил к ней withContext(Dispatchers.Main) и вроде все работает как надо. стала останавливаться. это мой косяк, что я withContext не указал или он не должен ни на что влиять?

Comment: @Wlad да, withContext проверяет, не отменена ли корутина, но это костыль, а не решение